# Log Failed File Access

Tags: files, log

I have a program that was written by a developer that no longer works for the company, on execution the program says that the path for the log files is not mounted.  The computer that this use to ran on has been wiped.

Is there any way (short of decompiling the application) to figure out what file path it is attempting to access?

Comment: Don't decompile, look at the source. If you don't have the source, delete the program and start again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [strace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/strace.1.html) to find out what filews to program is trying to access:

```
strace -e trace=file -f -y -o some.log your_program
```

will run `your_program` and log all file related syscalls of the program and its children into `some.log`